# Why basemap is not showing in QGIS with custom NTv2 crs?

Tags: qgis, basemap, land-survey, ntv2-transformation

I set up a custom CRS that uses a precise NTv2 transformation. I only have basemaps to test it with, but having more precise basemaps underlayed beneath my surveyed data is my primary goal. I am aware, that the basemaps will still not perfectly align, as they were not intended to be perfectly georeferenced to begin with, but at least I eliminate (most of) the error coming from the transformation to my target (project) CRS. If the project is set to the custom NTv2 based CRS, the basemap is not showing at all, without yielding an error.

**Context:**
My surveying data is in [EPSG:3844](https://epsg.org/crs_3844/Pulkovo-1942-58-Stereo70.html), but for it, the best available transformation to WGS84 (copied from ETRS89) implemented in PROJ is [EPSG:15995](https://epsg.org/transformation_15995/Pulkovo-1942-58-to-WGS-84-19.html), which is a Helmert transformation. It's decent, but as QGIS warns, only within 3 meters. Most often it's way better, but I can't rely on it. Fortunately, there are 2 .gsb files that I can use. One is [official](https://www.rompos.ro/index.php/informatii-tehnice/transdatro/download/2-software/60-grid-ntv2), and the other one is created by a company that made it public. They are equivalent.
I created the custom CRS in QGIS (Settings -> Custom Projections | Format: WKT) where I filled in the WKT1 code as it follows:

**WKT1:**

```
PROJCS["Pulkovo 1942(58) / Stereo70",
    GEOGCS["Pulkovo 1942(58)",
        DATUM["Pulkovo_1942_58",
            SPHEROID["Krassowsky 1940",6378245,298.3],
            EXTENSION["PROJ4_GRIDS","Stereo70_ETRS89.gsb"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4179"]],
    PROJECTION["Oblique_Stereographic"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",46],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",25],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.99975],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",500000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
```

When I went back and checked the same CRS, now coded USER:100001, it automatically got converted to WKT2, as:

**WKT2:**

```
BOUNDCRS[
    SOURCECRS[
        PROJCRS["Pulkovo 1942(58) / Stereo70",
            BASEGEOGCRS["Pulkovo 1942(58)",
                DATUM["Pulkovo 1942(58)",
                    ELLIPSOID["Krassowsky 1940",6378245,298.3,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                ID["EPSG",4179]],
            CONVERSION["unnamed",
                METHOD["Oblique Stereographic",
                    ID["EPSG",9809]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",46,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8801]],
                PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",25,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8802]],
                PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.99975,
                    SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8805]],
                PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8806]],
                PARAMETER["False northing",500000,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8807]]],
            CS[Cartesian,2],
                AXIS["(E)",east,
                    ORDER[1],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                AXIS["(N)",north,
                    ORDER[2],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",9133844]]],
    TARGETCRS[
        GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
            DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
                ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            ID["EPSG",4326]]],
    ABRIDGEDTRANSFORMATION["Pulkovo 1942(58) to WGS84",
        METHOD["NTv2",
            ID["EPSG",9615]],
        PARAMETERFILE["Latitude and longitude difference file","Stereo70_ETRS89.gsb",
            ID["EPSG",8656]]]]
```

and **PROJ4**:

```
+proj=sterea +lat_0=46 +lon_0=25 +k=0.99975 +x_0=500000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=krass +nadgrids=Stereo70_ETRS89.gsb +units=m +no_defs +type=crs
```

All the above look fine to me. Then I also copied the gsb file into the proj folder, but QGIS nevertheless complained about not finding the gsb file and asked me for it. I gave it the file, and it copied it under my profile's proj, where I should have copied it from the beginning.

Then I Set my project and my data layer to the new USER:100001 CRS (above). Then I added Google Satellite via QMS plugin, but it doesn't make a difference if I use the XYZ Tiles functionality in QGIS, or if I add any EPSG:3857 based WMS. Everything works just fine though if I set the project CRS to EPSG:3844, but then I don't benefit from the improved NTv2 transformation in the `Stereo70_ETRS89.gsb` file.

What gives?
What am I missing to do for the EPSG:3857 basemaps to show up, or perhaps they aren't supposed to work like this? But then why? How do I even start to debug this?